# Can't deploy web service on azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have been trying to create a web service all day in azure using node js,
I cannot seem to figure out what to do, every time I get a different issue,
I created a simple express app and committed to git, afterwards connected it to azure web app just like in this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zjnOTZxuEU

After that I am getting this page:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efo9S.png)

I tried to remove the hostingstart.html from the default document but then i am getting a page telling me I don't have permissions,
What to do in order to get it working?

You can see the express app here: https://github.com/orizvida/new

Comment: App Service might be more cost-effective for hosting than virtual machine, but I would recommend virtual machine if possible for the ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

Your API method has no path defined:

app.get('/',(req,res) => res.send("hello"));

Should be like:

app.get('/hellomessage',(req,res) => res.send("hello"));

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to this, you could follow this steps:

1. Create a simple express project by this command:

   ```
    npx express-generator
    npm install -g express-generator
    express
    express --view=pug {your-app-name}
    cd {your-app-name}
    npm install
   ```
2. Upload to GitHub. Here is the file structure:
   [image]
3. Create a Web App on Azure.
   [image]
4. Navigate to Deployment Center, set deployment from GitHub, choose your repository, and save settings.
5. Go to GitHub, and see the Action logs in your repository:
   [image]
6. Go to your website to see the result: `https://dorisnode.scm.azurewebsites.net/`, and go to this site to see the file structure: `https://{your-file-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/`
   [image]

---

If your Web App based on **Windows** while creating, you might need a `web.config` file to make **IIS** recognize your project, see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/project-nodejs-express-webapp/blob/master/Web.config).